# Error in accessing json data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

This is my ajax code

```
$.ajax({
        url:"jsoncontent.json",
        dataType:"json",
        success:function(data){
            var tem = data;
            var test ='facebook';
            alert(tem.facebook[0].name);//working
            alert(tem.test[0].name);//Why it is not Working?How can i access with test variable
                    //alert(tem.test+[2].name);tried    
            }   
        });
```

I got confused in accessing json data.. any help

Comment: did you try tem[test][0].name?

Comment: What does the resulting JSON look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [**Bracket notation**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators#Bracket_notation).

Thus use

```
alert(tem[test][0].name);
```

instead of

```
alert(tem.test[0].name);
```

EDIT: As per comments. You should visit [official jQuery.each() docs](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)

```
$.each(tem[test],function(index, value){ 
    alert(value.name);
});
```

Comment: Ya i got the answer.. i have one more doubt sir?how can i access via jquery each function sir?

Comment: @Koushik, Can you elaborate what you mean by `how can i access via jquery each function sir`

Comment: i want to access this individually like this tem[test][0].name,tem[test][1].name,... using jquery $.each(whatvalue?,function(k,v){ alert(how?);});

Comment: @Koushik, try `$.each(tem[test],function(index, value){ 
  alert(value.name);
 });`